# Display the taxonomy term as an image

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, media

I'm trying to display the taxonomy term (filter (Better Exposed Filters) on Views) as an image. I added an image field, upload an image (marker). Create template **views-view-field--maps--field-type.tpl.php**. I found example how to make theming of taxonomy-term here: http://www.milesjcarter.co.uk/blog/web-design-development/drupal-views-templating-tutorial-outputting-respective-image-fields-multiple-taxonomy-term-references

My code looks like:

```
if(isset($row->field_field_type)) {
    $term = $row->field_field_type;
    foreach($term as $type){
        render(field_view_field('taxonomy_term', $type['raw']['taxonomy_term'], 'field_marker', array('label'=>'hidden', 'settings' => array('image_style' => 'thumbnail'))));
    }
}
```

For some reason, the code does not replace taxonomy term, it just show me messages:

> Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference in include()
>   (line 8

What could be the reason? I would be grateful for any advice.

I try dpm:

```
dpm(render(field_view_field('taxonomy_term', $type['raw']['taxonomy_term'], 'field_marker', array('label'=>'hidden', 'settings' => array('image_style' => 'thumbnail')))));
```

And it show me this:

```
<div class="field field-name-field-marker field-type-image field-label-hidden"><div class="field-items"><div class="field-item even"><img typeof="foaf:Image" class="img-responsive" src="http://localhost/sites/default/files/styles/thumbnail/public/1.png?itok=A6-EJb27" width="63" height="100" alt="" /></div></div></div>
```

I know that there is a module [Taxonomy Image](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_image) I tried to install it, but after activation necessary functionality was not added to my site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got solution. Thanks [xandeadx](http://dru.io/question/8048) for the help

```
function MYMODULE_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
    foreach ($form['TAXONOMY_ELEMENT']['#options'] as $tid => &$name) {
        $term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
        $name = '<img src="' . file_create_url($term->FIELD_IMAGE['und'][0]['uri']) . '" />';
    }
}
```

TAXONOMY_ELEMENT = tid_1

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do it. The easiest way would be to use views. You can create a view of taxonomy terms with only an image field and display it as a view block.

See an example of view below.

[image: Views]
[image: Views Result]

Let me know if you need any help.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I use the taxonomy term for filtering (Better Exposed Filters) as checkboxes. Is it possible in this case to use the solution you have proposed?

Comment: This worked out great! Thank you!!! I didn't have to install any new modules. That's always a win